# Which functions $\mathbb C \to\mathbb C$ can be written as $f(z,\bar z)$ for holomorphic $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

To rephrase the question more precisely than in the title, I'm interested in functions $g:U\to\mathbb C$ for $U$ open in $\mathbb C$ such that for each $z'\in U$ there's a neighbourhood $U'\subseteq U$ of $z'$ and a holomorphic function $f:{U'}^2\to\mathbb C$ such that $g(z)=f(z,\bar z)$ for all $z\in U'$. So for example the absolute value function $\mathbb C - \{0\}\to\mathbb C$ is an example since $|z|=\sqrt{z\bar z}$ even though there's no global holomorphic squareroot function.

I know that the harmonic functions are precisely the ones which are a sum of a holomorphic and antiholomorphic function, but this is more general than that. I can see that such a function has to be infinitely differentiable, but that's pretty much all I can get. Can all infinitely differentiable functions be written in such a way?

Comment: I thought of this question while thinking about category theory. Many constructions in category theory that aren't functorial can nevertheless be written as $G(z)=F(z,z)$ for some functor $F$ which is covariant in its first argument and contravariant in its second. The canonical example being $\mathrm{End}(z)=\mathrm{Hom}(z,z)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are just the real-analytic functions.  Indeed, since $x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ and $y=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$, any real-analytic function on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ can be written locally as a power series in $z$ and $\bar{z}$, and conversely any power series in $z$ and $\bar{z}$ can also be viewed as a power series in $x$ and $y$.